# ps -ef | grep tomcat shows only 3 - 4 processes running

Tags: tomcat7

I am running a Tomcat 7 Servlet container, and i am trying to observe the number of Tomcat processes running in the background.

`ps - ef | grep tomcat` shows 3 - 4 processes running, even at its busiest load. Am i missing something with the ps command, or is that really how Tomcat runs?

Ps: I have configured at least 200 threads in settings.xml.

```
<Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-pool-exec-" maxThreads="10000" minSpareThreads="200"/>

<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" connectionUploadTimeout="36000000" connectionTimeout="600000" acceptCount="0" URIEncoding="UTF-8" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Answer (score 2):

There should only be one process per Tomcat instance. To see individual threads, you can add the `L` switch to your `ps` command, e.g.:

```
ps -efL | grep tomcat
```